# Programming language grammar

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, binary-tree, grammar

I have this question in a Compilers coursework but I don't really know how to approach it. Could anyone please give me a better hint than what was given in the rubric?

> Show that all binary strings generated by the following grammar have values 
>   divisible by 3.
>
> Hint: use induction on the numerical values for nodes in the parse tree.
>
> ```
> num -> 11 | 1001 | num 0 | num num
> ```

Comment: @DavidStratton: Eh? Induction is like basic maths technique, hardly a "showing off" word. If you're learning about compilers, you should know about induction already. It's kid of like complaining that "water" is a bragadoccio word.

Comment: @Amadan - *LOL*  Point taken.  Comment removed.  it was out of place anyway.  I'm just so many years out of school that I have to think hard to remember terms I never use in day-to-day life.  I'm just a geezer with failing memory is all.  Bragadoccio - that's good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two hints:

1. Appending a 0 to a binary representation is equivalent to multiplication by 2.
2. Appending a binary representation to itself is equivalent to multiplication by 2^N + 1.

Comment: Ok, so essentially we're going to get to a point where we connect to either 11 or 1001. Other than those two, num num is also divisible by 3. So num 0 is just doubling a value divisible by 3. Correct?